# Can't connect to VM's Postgresql server?

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, remote-access

Basically I'm trying to connect to a postgresql server hosted on a GCP's VM. I've created the database there, I've changed my firewall to allow connections on port 5432, added this --> " listen_addresses = '*' " to my postgresql.config file, and added my local machine's external IP address to the list of accepted IPs on the pg_hba.conf file with the trust method. Has anyone got any idea what could be wrong here? I just keep getting this error

```
postgres@LAPTOP-14QDEC1P:/mnt/d/random path $ psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx api_fp
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

the port to listen on is also set to 5432.

Comment: Is the database running?  What does the log file say?  Can you connect using psql on the same machine where the database is (supposed to be) running?

Comment: Connection Refused means the connection is getting past the firewall but most likely PostgreSQL is refusing the connection. Most likely you have entered the wrong IP address for your local system. For problems like this be very specific about what you configured and where you are connecting from. Vague terms like local machine can mean many things.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow the Google Cloud Firewall rule on the VPC as well to make it work. you can open your Google Cloud Shell from the console in the project and run the following gcloud command to allow the firewall rule for all instances in the vpc network:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-postgres \
--allow tcp:5432 \
--direction INGRESS \
--source-ranges <yourhomeipaddress> \
--network <your-vpc-name>
```

For docs on this you can read:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls